# inheritance with android style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have defined red color to contentBg style for TextView. Can i change the TextView color red to blue by changing or renaming style name myContentNew from the parent style? The TextView style name-contentBG should not be changed. Is it possible in android sytle.

```
<RelativeLayout 
   style="@style/myContent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView 
   style="@style/contentBG"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My code should be like below

```
<RelativeLayout 
       style="@style/myContentNew"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
       style="@style/contentBG"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

You can get clear idea with my attached image.[image]

**like CSS:**

```
.myContent .contentBg{background-color:red}
.myContentNew .contentBg{background-color:blue}
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems you are tryin to setup a theme right? Do you need to do this in one layout or all the layouts?

Comment: Actually i would like to use this as active or inactive state with the above requirements

Comment: I don't think you can setup this kind of inheritance directly. The only way I see is to setup 2 themes and use styles as references that will change according to the theme selected.

Comment: Can u please show me how can we do that?

Comment: I added an answer, I hope it's clear enough!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not.

Once the `contentBG` style is set. It can't be changed but in code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with the creation of 2 different themes:

You need first to modify your manifest file to call the default custom theme, for example:

```
<application
    android:name="RateDayApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
```

Then, in your styles.xml file, prepare 2 different themes, containing the same style `contentBG`:

```
<!-- *** THEME WITH RED BG*** -->
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="contentBG">@style/contentBGred</item>

</style>

<style name="contentBGred" >
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/red</item>
</style>

<!-- *** THEME WITH BLUE BG*** -->
<style name="CustomThemeNew" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="contentBG">@style/contentBGblue</item>
</style>

<style name="contentBGblue" >
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

**IMPORTANT:** here I use `Theme.Holo.Light` as parent theme, you can change it if you are using a different one.

In the 2 themes above, the style has the same name, it will be use as a reference in your XML files. In order to declare this reference, you must add it in the file untitled `attrs.xml` under your `values` folder.

Here is the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <attr name="contentBG" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Once it is done, you just need to call this style this way in your XML files (you don't need the style on the layout anymore):

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView 
   style="?contentBG"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The question mark here means that the style will be loaded using a reference. The style that will be used will be the one of the current theme applied on the `Activity`.

You can easily setup the theme you want on your activity using this way:

```
setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme);
```

or

```
setTheme(R.style.CustomThemeNew);
```